# PHP HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE When does it send response?

Tags: php

Have a small script which I read in an http buffer, send an http_response_back (Usually either a 200 or 401) and then process the data.

My question is does the response get sent immediately once the http_response_code is executed, or does a buffer need to be flushed to force the send?

Seems to work fine with small amounts of data but when large amounts are received it starts to fail. The sender has a timeout of 5 seconds and seems to timeout but I can see from traces that the http_response_code is executed within 1-2 seconds of receiving the payload. Same time as the the smaller payloads.

I'm wondering if there needs to be a buffer flush that needs to take place to send the actual response.

Any ideas much appreciated.

TIA 
Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't send immediately. The description of the function indicates that you can call it repeatedly to change the response code -- each time you call it, it returns the previous code and saves the new code. When the response is actually sent, the last reply code that was set will be used. If it sent immediately, it would make no sense to be able to change it, since you can't send the response code multiple times.

It will be sent the same time as headers are sent (since the reply code precedes the headers), which is before any output is sent. Flushing the output buffer should force it immediately.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Barmar for the response. Makes total sense.